# Is this fact true about closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a continuous function $f:[1,6]\to\mathbb{R}$. And I form a partition of this closed interval of non-overlapping closed sets. For example, a partition can be
$$[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]$$

Let $t_k$ denote the sequence of local maxima of $f$ for each of the sets. So,
$$t_k=\operatorname{max}\{f(x)|x\in I_k\}$$,where $I_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ interval. Now, suppose I define the sequence 
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nt_kL_k$$, where $L_k$ is the length of the $k^{th}$ interval. Here, $n$ is the number of closed intervals in the partition.

So, my question is, is $S_n$ a monotonic decreasing sequence? I think it is, but I need a proof of this fact. Is this even true? I have a geometrical proof in mind, consisting of areas of rectangles. But, I am not sure if it is applicable to all partitions.

Comment: The partition you have is overlapping.

Comment: Also how do you define the partition? Are you partitioning in a specific way say $[a+k(b-a)/n,a+(k+1)(b-a)/n)$? Otherwise the $S_n$ is not well defined and if you allow an arbitrary partition for each $n$ you certainly can't get monotonicity. Consider $x^2$ on $[0,4]$ and take the first partition to be $[0,3],(3,4]$ and the second $[0,1/2],(1/2,1](1,4]$ The first sums to 43 the second to a bit over 48.

Comment: What *is* true (and not hard to prove), is that if one partition is a *refinement* of another, meaning each subinterval in the refinement is contained in some interval of the original, then the sum associated with the refinement is $\le$ the sum associated with the original. This simple fact is in fact quite useful in studying the Riemann integral.

Comment: @DRF, I presume you consider it overlapping because $[1,2]\cap [2,3]=\{2\}$ If this is so, then yeah, they are overlapping. I am not partitioning in a specific way, just that each interval has to be closed, and it should be of the above form.

Comment: If you allow overlapping in the way you do it gets even worse. Also the question says closed sets but you seem to be using intervals. With closed sets you can make the series behave really bad pretty much getting any numbers between the actual riemann integral (assuming one exists) and maximum time length of interval you're integrating over. Just choose a couple normal intervals and then grab a couple that you add the global maximum to, sets stay closed and you've completely broken the sum.

Comment: If  the $(n+1)th$ partition $P_{n+1}$ is a refinement of the $n$th partition $P_n$, that is, if each interval of $P_n$ is the union of a set of members of $P_{n+1}$, then $S_{n+1}\leq S_n. $.... Because  for $p\in P_n$, if $Q_p$ is the set of members of $P_{n+1}$ that are subsets of $p$, then for each $q\in Q_p$ we have $t_q=\max_{x\in q}f(x)\leq \max_{x\in p}f(x)=t_p$..... So $\sum_{q\in Q_p}L(q)t_q\leq \sum_{q\in Q_p}L(q)t_p=L(p)t_p.$.... (Where $L(b)$ denotes the length of an interval $b$.)..... Summing this over all $p\in P$ gives $S_{n+1}\leq S_n.$